# counter examples for Riemann and Lebesgue integrabilities

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm seeking interesting examples that are not mentioned in usual real analysis texts.
It seems that in general there is no relationship between Riemann integrability and Lebesgue integrability when the function is unbounded or the integral is over an unbounded interval. For example, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}1_{(n,n+1)}$ are Riemann integrable (RI for short) but not Lebesgue integrable (LI for short) over $(0,\infty)$. We can modify the second example to make an unbounded function on $[0,1]$ which is RI but not LI.

We also know that $f$ is LI iff $|f|$ is LI. However, this is not true when it comes to RI (e.g. $f(x)=-1$ or $1$ depending whether $x$ is rational or not; another example is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$). Now consider the following example pattern:

$f$ is/isn't RI AND $|f|$ is/isn't RI AND $f$ is/isn't LI.

Basically we impose three properties to $f$ and for each property we can assign "is" or "is not". So there are 8 possibilities. I myself am able to find examples for five of them. But I can't find the following three:

1. Is there a function $f$ such that $f$ is RI and $|f|$ is RI and $f$ is not LI?
2. Is there a function $f$ such that $f$ is not RI and $|f|$ is RI and $f$ is not LI?
3. Is there a function $f$ such that $f$ is RI and $|f|$ is not RI and $f$ is LI?

Of course all the integrals are taken over the same single interval (most likely unbounded).

These counter examples are very interesting and can deepen our understanding of RI and LI. I'm also seeking more counter example such as:

4. Is there a function $h$ such that $h$ is Riemann and Lebesgue integrable but their values are unequal?
5. Is there a function $h$ such that $|h|$ is Riemann and Lebesgue integrable but their values are unequal?

Comment: Check out "Counterexamples in analysis" if you can. Great, interesting book. I'd be surprised if any one of these wasn't in there.

Comment: The interval cannot be unbounded if the function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @zhw. Why? $1/x^2$ is Riemann integrable over $[1,\infty)$

Comment: No, Riemann integrability assumes a closed bounded interval in its definition. The *improper* Riemann integral of $1/x^2$ over $[1,\infty)$ converges.

Comment: @zhw. When I said Riemann integral I actually included the improper case (implicitly by saying the interval may be unbounded). Sorry for my unclear statement.

Comment: @MoseWintner I got this book but found no such examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Riemann integrability implies Lebesgue integrability, in which case the values of the integrals are equal, taking care of 1, 3, and 4. Since the absolute value function is continuous, and the composition of a continuous function with a Riemann integrable function is Riemann integrable, 2 is false.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Good question. My only correction would be to say the answer to 2. is "no" rather than "false". I upvoted.

Comment: @Nitin Riemann integrability does NOT imply Lebesgue integrability in general: e.g. "alternating series" $(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}1 _{(n,n+1)}$and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: Riemann integrability on a compact interval $[a,b]$ implies Lebesgue integralibility. HOWEVER, in the general case, (which includes the so called improper Riemann integrals)  Riemann integrability does NOT imply Lebesgue integrability. It is related to "alternating series" as Dony pointed out.

Comment: @RamiroGuerreiro I agree with the theorem you mentioned. In fact it was that theorem motivated my question: I want to know what happens in other cases.

Comment: @Dony You wrote "We also know that $f$ is LI iff $|f|$ is LI.".  Well this is true IF $f$ is measurable.  However, there are functions $f$ such that $f$ is NOT measurable, but  $|f|$ is measurable.  So, there are functions such that $f$ is not LI, but $|f|$ is LI. For instance: let $E$ be a non-measurable set such that $E \subseteq [0,1]$.  Let $f=\chi_E-\chi_{([0,1]-E)}$.   $f$ is not measurable, is not LI, but $|f|= \chi_{[0,1]}$, so $|f|$ is measurable and LI.